# Finding specific info of a line in a text file

Tags: c, file, import, lines

Can't seem to find any info anywhere on how i find info from a specific line in a .txt file.
Like the line could be results from hockey matches,
the line could look like:

> 19.00    01.01.2010  Team1 - Team2   5 - 10  2000
>
> 20.00    02.20.2010  Team2 - Team3   7 - 11  3400
>
> 19.00    03.30.2010  Team1 - Team4   4 - 4   1000

and so on ...

So if I wanted just to get the out print from the match with team3 and team4?

This is what I have at the moment, but if I want to type 2 - 2 and get every line that has the number 2 in it.

Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void ){
    char target [ 64 ];
    printf( "Enter a score:" );
    scanf("%s",&target );

    static const char filNavn[] = "text";
    FILE *fil = fopen( filNavn, "r" );
    if ( fil != NULL ){
        char line [ 64 ];

        while( fgets( line, sizeof line, fil ) != NULL ){

            if ( strstr( line, target ) != NULL ){
                printf("%s\n", line);
            }
        }
        fclose( fil );
    }
    else{
         perror( filNavn );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should list all the combinations that you want to show and some examples of the files content.

Comment: Okay ill throw some more lines in

Answer (score 0):

If you are so sure of the format of the line in the file then you can use `sscanf`. Say for example

```
int score = atoi(target);
while( fgets( line, sizeof line, fil ) != NULL ){
int t1, t2, s1, s2;
sscanf(line, "Team%d vs Team%d %d-%d", &t1, &t2, &s1, &s2);
if (s1 == score || s2 == score)
    /* Do something here */
}
```

Comment: Should i replace this with my prior while or just copy it in?

Comment: You have to change the above code, based on your needs. I assumed the format `Team1 vs Team2 2-2`. If any spaces are there include them also.

Comment: Hmm what if i only want to find the matches which ended 2 - 2?

Comment: or a match where there has been more than 3 goals in it?

Comment: `s1` and `s2` are the two result scores. You can use them the way you want.

Comment: This is not enough sometimes he wants to find another type of information.

Comment: Can u just explain your input format. Is that just a number or has some specific format?

Comment: 19.00 01.01.2010 Team1 - Team2 5 - 10 2000

    20.00 02.20.2010 Team2 - Team3 7 - 11 3400

    19.00 03.30.2010 Team1 - Team4 4 - 4 1000 they go like this, a long line, so i would like to know how i get the team results and so on into a variable so i can print out specific info

Comment: If u need just the scores then u can extend the above format to get it. I mean to add the time and date before. Or `sscanf` has some regular expressions, u can use them to extract the data from the line.

Answer (score 0):

Some mistakes I see:

1. In the `code-line 7` it should be:

   ```
   /* Let's leave it easy, there are somethings you must 
      read about safety reading. */
   gets( target );
   ```

PD: You added an ampersand (&) before target if you want to use that syntax it should have been, `&target[ 0 ]`;

1. In the `code-line 12` you declared a new variable, It isn't good to do that so I suggest You do declare it where you declared the target string.
2. In the example you said that your data is saved in slots of `42 characters`, so scan in the same size `code-line 12`.

   ```
   char line[ 43 ].
   ```
3. In tis same way then your target shouldn't be bigger than line `code-line 5`.

   ```
   char target[ 43 ].
   ```
4. About the `strstr()` function, it works this way [Cplusplus strstr() behavior description](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/):

> *Locate substring ( strstr() ). Returns a pointer to the first occurrence of str2 in str1, or a null pointer if str2 is not part of str1.*

Comment: Thank you Again Alberto, my text file im reading for doesnt have a .txt in the end, and when i write .txt, it wont read, but it ll read if i dont write it. Atm i have it so i can find every match with the same result now :) But i would also like how to find all the matches where the has been more than 3 goals in it, if you can help me with that?